# Bubble sorting in Ascending - program won't compile

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point, bubble-sort

I need to write a program that uses a bubble sorting method and main function that asks for a user to input their array. After which the program sorts the array in ascending order. My program right now asks the for the user's input, but once that happens, the program won't compile and I'm stuck. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IntSorter{
  public static int bubbleSort(int[] a){
    boolean needNextPass =true;
    for(int i=1; i<a.length && needNextPass; i++){
      needNextPass = false;
      for(int j=0; j<a.length - i; j++){
        if(a[j]> a[j+1]){
          int temp = a[j];
          a[j]=a[j+1];
          a[j+1] = temp;
          needNextPass = true;
          }
        }
      }
   for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
     System.out.print(a[j] + " ");
     }
   }
public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter size of array: ");
  int N = input.nextInt();
  int[] x = new int[N];
  System.out.print("Enter " +N +"numbers of your array: ");
    for(int i= 0; i<N; i++){
      x[i] = input.nextInt()
  }
  IntSorter access = new IntSorter();
  System.out.print("Your sorted array is: ");
  access.IntSorter(x);}
}
```

Comment: `but once that happens, the program won't compile ` : -How can your program not compile after you are already running it??

Comment: What message are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You last line in your main method is : -

```
access.IntSorter(x);
```

Replace this line with: -

```
access.bubbleSort(x);
```

And using `single uppercase` character as variable is terrible.. use `size` instead for size of array..

```
System.out.print("Enter " +N +"numbers of your array: ");
  for(int i= 0; i<N; i++){
      x[i] = input.nextInt()
  }
```

And in the above code, what if user didn't enter an integer value?? You will get an exception.. You need to catch that..

Comment: Okay, I fixed all the errors you pointed out, and the program's running. Thanks

Comment: @ChaseChensta.. Congrats.. :).. But do consider handling your `exception` that can come through user input..

Comment: @ChaseChensta.. And you need to accept one of the answers by clicking the big arrow on the left side of each question..

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be missing a semicolon:

```
  x[i] = input.nextInt()
```

And you seem to be access a variable `j` outside of its scope:

```
  System.out.print(a[j] + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `i` instead of `j` which is undefined:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
}
```

Also

```
public static int bubbleSort(int[] a) {
```

has no `int` return value;

You can use your compiler or IDE to help highlight these issues.